# When using a microscope, why do we need to send waves through a specimen to see it?

Tags: optics, microscopy

I was curious about microscopes and I looked up how they work. The article I read(https://www.explainthatstuff.com/electronmicroscopes.html)mentioned that waves are passed through a specimen to see it. Waves that could be used include waves from electrons or that of light. I was curious as to how these waves interact with a specimen and how this interaction leads to us seeing the specimen magnified?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not all microscopes depend on "waves travelling through a specimen". The highest magnifications, down to less than the diameter of an atom, are obtained with the [Scanning Tunnelling Microscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanning_tunneling_microscope). The STM uses a tiny probe that is brought to within less than 1nm of the surface to scan. As it is moved sideways, it senses the change in height of the surface and moves the probe up and down to compensate. The pattern of movements of the probe is used to show the surface of the sample on a screen.

However, all microscopes, including the STM, need to interact with the sample. Without any interaction it would be impossible to know the sample is even there. If light did not interact with items around you, you would not be able to see them - although you might be able to feel, hear or smell them (different interactions). In the STM, this interaction is via [quantum tunnelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_tunnelling) between the probe and the sample.

In a conventional microscope, the interaction is the same as in ordinary vision: light waves are modified by the sample (and the lenses in the microscope), and we see the result. With an electron microscope, the sample deflects the path of electrons. These electrons then interact with a detector, and this interaction is shown to the user on a screen.

To repeat, you can only observe objects through some interaction with them. The actual interaction, and the method used to show it to us, depends on the type of microscope you use.